# Using custom struct to store results in map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++14, dynamic-programming

I am using the following program to solve a dynamic programming question using recursion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int getMax(int a[], int start, int end){
    int i,m=0;
    for(i=start;i<end;i++){
        if(a[i]>m){
            m = a[i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}

int getanswer(int a[], int k,int prevstart, int start, int end, int total){
    if(start == end && k!=0){
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    else if(k == 1){
        return total + getMax(a,start,end);
    }
        
        return min(getanswer(a,k-1,start+1,start+1,end,total+getMax(a,prevstart,start+1)), getanswer(a,k,prevstart,start+1,end,total));
        
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {74303,20452,66120,44483,5370,68585};
    int  k = 5;
    cout<<getanswer(a,k,0,0,6,0);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives 234830 as output which is correct.
Now, I am creating a custom struct and using a map to store the results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

struct Test { 
    int k;
    int prevstart;
    int start;
    int end;
}; 

bool operator<(const Test& t1, const Test& t2) 
{ 
    return (t1.k < t2.k) || (t1.k == t2.k && t1.prevstart < t2.prevstart) || 
    (t1.k == t2.k && t1.prevstart == t2.prevstart && t1.start < t2.start) ||
    (t1.k == t2.k && t1.prevstart == t2.prevstart && t1.start == t2.start && t1.end < t2.end); 
} 

map<Test,int> dp;
int getMax(int a[], int start, int end){
    int i,m=0;
    for(i=start;i<end;i++){
        if(a[i]>m){
            m = a[i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}

int getanswer(int a[], int k,int prevstart, int start, int end, int total){
    Test temp = {k,prevstart,start,end};
    if(dp.count(temp)){
        return dp[temp];
    }
    if(start == end && k!=0){
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    else if(k == 1){
        dp[temp] = total + getMax(a,start,end);
        return dp[temp];
    }
        
        dp[temp] = min(getanswer(a,k-1,start+1,start+1,end,total+getMax(a,prevstart,start+1)), getanswer(a,k,prevstart,start+1,end,total));
        return dp[temp];
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {74303,20452,66120,44483,5370,68585};
    int  k = 5;
    cout<<getanswer(a,k,0,0,6,0);
    return 0;
}
```

But, now it gives 258861 as output. I suspect I am doing something wrong while overloading < operator. What am I missing here?

Comment: To summarize: we don't know what problem you are trying to solve; your code compiles and executes correctly; and you hope someone might tell you why your program doesn't solve the problem which we don't know about?

Comment: I am trying to store all return results in a map and use it when needed.

Comment: Can you try your program with much smaller values, so we get something a bit more meaningful than "258861" or "234830"? Even better, could you try to isolate which parts of your program work as intended and which don't, so we only need to look at the smaller part of the code which doesn't?

Comment: try to use c++17's std::tie for comparison (operator<) like this:
`bool operator<(const Test& t1, const Test& t2) { return std::tie(t1.k, t1.prevstart, t1.start, t1.end) < std::tie(t2.k, t2.prevstart, t2.start, t2.end); }`

Comment: Your `operator<` looks correct if it is supposed to implement lexicographical order. Your `getmax` function looks correct, but only under the assumption that `a` contains at least one nonnegative integer. I suspect the problem is with `getanswer`.

Comment: @Stef Yes, a will only contain non-negative integers. The only change I am making in getanswer is to return results from the map if it exists or store the result in the map if it does not exist.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I tried using tie. Still getting the same error.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Could it be that `getanswer` is called with the same values for `k,prevstart,start,end` but different values for `total`? When you memoize the value in the map, you don't account for `total`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first program, `getanswer` is sometimes called with the same values for `k`, `prevstart`, `start` and `end` but different values for `total`. Whereupon it of course returns different results.

In the second program, `getanswer` is, naturally, also sometimes called with the same values for `k`, `prevstart`, `start` and `end` but different values for `total`. However, it returns the same result from these calls - namely, the result the first such call computed and stored in the map.